# SQL delete query. 100000 rows to delete

Tags: sql-server

Evening all,

I am requiring to delete a large number of rows in my database. The difficulty is the conditions where I need the rows to delete are all different (50000) in total

For example

```
Delete * from [TableA]
where [columnA] in (‘1’,’2’,’3’,’4’)      50000 separate             column values
and [columnB] in (‘1’,’2’)           just the 2 column values
```

Due to the variety of the column A values I am struggling to implement any kind of row count or deleting 1000 at a time as the query is failing as it still needs to look through all 50000 values.

Any ideas how I can do what is required without locking any tables down, or if they need to be locked then in optimum speed.

Thanks!!!

Comment: put those 50000 values in a table and use `IN (SELECT Column FROM NewTable)` or `EXISTS(….`

Comment: Thanks I’ll give that a go tomorrow when back in work

Comment: Also possible - SELECT the unique key for the matched rows into a temp table, and use that table as the driver, e.g.: `CREATE TABLE #tmp (UK bigint, [id] int identity); INSERT INTO #tmp (UK) Select RowKey From MyTable WHERE <matching conditions here>;`  You now have a table with a sequential id field for easy batching and the appropriate unique keys for identifying the rows to be deleted.

Comment: Very much appreciated thank you, will let you know how I get on

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve the problem by creating a table in a new data base I created (thanks to Lamak)
Appendix;

[TableA]: Table where 10000 entries needed to be deleted in [databaseA.dbo.tableA]

[TableB]: New table created in new database [databaseB.dbo.tableB]

**Ensure you are connected to database you want to delete the entries from.

Delete from [TableB] where [conditionA] in
(Select [ConditionA] from [databaseB.dbo.tableB])

** I also built in some regression for the query to rollback in the event of any errors, if errors are detected it will rollback if not the query will commit itself. If anyone reading is interested in this reply and I can go back to my original script to get it as I can’t remember from the top of my head.

Thank you all for your help! :)